# Simple PHP hit counter incrementing by two?

Tags: php, increment, hitcounter

I made a hit counter for a web app, but am confused as to why it's incrementing by two. I simply set a counter variable from the hitCount.txt file, which contains an integer and write the pre-incremented value back to the file.

The code in question:

```
    // get visit count
    $wag_file = "hitCount.txt";
    $fh = fopen($wag_file, 'r+');
    $wag_visit_count = intval(file_get_contents($wag_file));
    // increment, rewrite, and display visit count
    fputs($fh, ++$wag_visit_count);
    fclose($fh);
    echo $wag_visit_count . $html_br;
```

Comment: try using `intval(trim(file_get_contents($wag_file)))`

Comment: I've seen others use trim as a rule, but wasn't sure of the necessity if this is the only thing writing to it and no whitespace is written. What's the conventional thought on this?

Comment: `intval` ignores whitespace (including \r \n \t) and any trailing garbage or whitespace after the numbers. So you normally wouldn't need `trim`.

Comment: @mario: good info... i had no idea i always use `(type)` to cast values... perhaps i shoudl rethink that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the most logical explanation is that your PHP script is called twice.

Take a look at what's called by the browser, using for example the Net tab of [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/).

A typical example is an `<img>` tag with an empty `src` : the browser will consider the empty `src` points to the current page -- and reload the current URL.

As a sidenote : instead of reading the file and only then writing it back, you should open your file in read/write mode, and lock it, to avoid concurrent writes -- see [**`flock()`**](http://fr.php.net/flock).

Basically, as you are already opening the file in r+ mode, you should use something like [**`fgets()`**](http://fr.php.net/fgets) to read from it -- and not `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go back and make it more robust. Need to put put file existence check in, too.

Comment: Ah, very good catch! I had pasted it into a test php template with a bad CSS link. Now fixed.